# Rewriting infinite product

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm trying to rewrite the infinite product $\prod{1-p_i}$ as a sum.. I notice this pattern in the terms... for instance if I expand for n = 4 ..

$+ 1$

$- (p_1 + p_2 + p_3 + p_4 ) $

$+ ((p_1 p_2 ) + (p_1 p_3 ) + (p_1 p_4 ) + (p_2 p_3 ) + (p_2 p_4 ) + (p_3 p_4 )) $

$- ((p_1 p_2 p_3 ) + (p_1 p_2 p_4 ) + (p_1 p_3 p_4 ) + ( p_2 p_3 p_4 ) ) $

$+ (p_1 p_2 p_3 p_4 ) $

I'm trying to figure out how to represent the 3 groups in the middle in terms of a sum of products or something... is there an accepted syntax or something for an "infinite combination" or whatever you'd call it?

Comment: What you are looking for is the [Elementary symmetric polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial) $e_k$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sum is $$\prod_{i=1}^n (1-p_i) = \sum_{\{i_1,i_2,\ldots ,i_k\}\subseteq [n]} (-1)^k p_{i_1} p_{i_2} \cdots p_{i_k}.$$ To see this, note that every term in the expanded product is formed as the product of, for each product term $1-p_i$, either $-p_i$ or $1$. The ones don’t contribute to these products so we can focus on the $-p_i$ terms, giving the result.

Comment: @cdipaolo --- thank you for your answer.  How would you write out the part you have under the summation symbol in english?  Is there a word for that sort of summation notation?

Comment: @scl The “$\subseteq$” symbol means “is a subset of,” while the “$[n]$” symbol is a symbolic shortcut for the set $\{1,2,\ldots ,n\}$. In other words, we are summing “over all index subsets of the numbers 1 through $n$.”